# VB.NET GetClientRect using framework

Tags: .net, vb.net, window, drawing

I would like to know if there is a framework-base method for the "GetClientRect" API or if I really have to invoke it.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for Me.ClientRectangle?

Comment: I would like to call it for a "foreign" window which is not part of my application.

Comment: Not for external windows, no.